# ASP.NET MVC 4 Routing issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to get to this url in my browser:

```
http://localhost:41359/account/login
```

Here are my Routes from my RouteConfig.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace CTHRC.Roti.Web.UI
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Account",
                url: "account/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to goto this URL in my browser, I get this error:

```
{"Message":No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:41359/account'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'account'."}
```

Everything seems right here, but I still get this error. Here is my AccountController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using CTHRC.Roti.Domain.Api.Services;

namespace CTHRC.Roti.Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("ModelContext", "Users", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(FormCollection form)
        {
            bool success = WebSecurity.Login(form["username"], form["password"], false);
            if (success)
            {
                string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
                if (returnUrl == null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("/home/index?userID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("UserDb", "Users", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(FormCollection form)
        {
            WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(form["username"], form["password"], new { Email = form["email"], Language = form["language"] });
            Response.Redirect("/account/login");
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            Response.Redirect("/account/login");
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

I have been struggling with this issue for days now, I have cleaned my solution, re-built my solution and built my solution and I still get that error. If anyone can help me that would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you put your `Default` route after your `Account` route?

Comment: My Default route is after my Account route, doesnt matter what order, I get the same error when I goto: `http://localhost:41359/account/login`

Comment: As per the error message It seems you are not passing the action name in URL.

Comment: One more thing if you have two projects or areas in your application then you have to include the Assembly name in the route as well so MVC can find the correct controller. And make sure your controller is in correct directory.. it should not be in Web API Controller to map this url